# How to get value only for the current month

Tags: sql, date

I would like to know if we can got values from date if the date is in the current month

For example, If I have :

```
date         value
28/06/2021   50
02/07/2021   100

05/07/2021   18
```

Then I search to have :

```
02/07/2021   100

05/07/2021   18
```

because 28/06/2021 is not in the current month

thanks in advance !

Comment: Please *Tag* the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you can use now() and month() functions to get the current date ang extract the month.

```
Select * 
from table
where <your filters>
having MONTH(NOW()) = MONTH( table.date_field)
```

Different databases like oracle , postrest change the name of this  functions , so you must find it

Answer (score 0):

TSQL

```
select * from tbl
where MONTH(date)=month(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to match the YEAR along with the MONTH if you will have data that spans more than a year.

```
SELECT date, value
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```